# I was working on a notes app and completed it when I tried making it an apk it shows me this error

Tags: android, database, kotlin, kapt

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

i have tried to change the java version from 17 to 20 but it showed me another error
and this is my build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "ir.hmoda7y.notes"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "ir.hmoda7y.notes"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.5.1")
    val room_version = "2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")


    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Comment: You should downgrade your Java version to 1.8 or upgrade it to 17 in the project settings.

Comment: Go to project settings -> SDK location -> JDK location (gradle) -> choose Java 17 or download it then select it and make sure the grade version of version 17. Please look at it following link. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html